# What is the long-term effect of a continuous off-set force, acting in a frictionless environment?

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics

An example would be if a satellite had a rocket on one edge, which were to fire continuously. 
I can see that there will be both lateral and rotational acceleration, but what I am less clear on is whether the satellite will follow an expanding spiral (this seems the most likely to me, but I cannot prove it), a contracting spiral, a circle, or some other path. 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

An object has a rocket (which, for simplicity, is fixed to the object so it always fires along a line perpendicular to the line between the rocket and the center of mass) which is offset from the center of mass by a distance d.  The force from that rocket, assuming it is constant in magnitude, will produce the following amount of force:

$$\vec{F}_{rocket} = F_0(cos(\theta)~\hat{x} + sin(\theta)~\hat{y})$$

The rocket will obey the following torque equation:
$$ \Sigma \tau = I \alpha$$

The torque, $\tau$, is given by $\tau = \vec{F_{rocket}} \times \vec{r}$, which in our situation gives us $\tau = F_0 d \hat{z}$.  Therefore,

$$ F_0 d ~\hat{z} = I \ddot \theta ~\hat{z}$$

$$\ddot \theta = \frac{F_0 d}{I}$$

$$\theta = \frac{F_0 d}{2 I} t^2 + \omega_0 t + \theta_0$$

Assuming without loss of generality that the objects starts at rest (and not rotating) with $\theta = 0$,

$$\theta = \frac{F_0 d}{2 I} t^2$$

Newton's 2nd law gives us $\Sigma \vec{F} = m \vec{a}$, which evaluates to

$$ F_0(cos(\theta)~\hat{x} + sin(\theta)~\hat{y}) = m \vec{a}$$

$$ F_0(cos(\frac{F_0 d}{2 I} t^2)~\hat{x} + sin(\frac{F_0 d}{2 I} t^2)~\hat{y}) = m \vec{a}$$

This gives us two equations for the x and y components of the object's position:

$$\ddot x = \frac{F_0}{m} cos(\frac{F_0 d}{2 I} t^2) $$
$$\ddot y = \frac{F_0}{m} sin(\frac{F_0 d}{2 I} t^2) $$

This does not admit exact closed-form solutions, but [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20as%20T%20goes%20to%20infinity%20of%20the%20integral%20of%20cos%28t%5E2%29%20over%20t%20from%200%20to%20T) tells me that in the limit of infinite time, integrating this once gives us

$$\dot x = \sqrt{\frac{\pi I F_0}{4 m^2 d}}, ~~ \dot y = \sqrt{\frac{\pi I F_0}{4 m^2 d}}$$

I'm not sure exactly what the object will do initially, but after a while, the object will settle into a nearly constant velocity of $\sqrt{\frac{\pi I F_0}{2 m^2 d}}$ at an angle of $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The maths is a bit beyond me but, the way I read your final line, it seems to be supporting my theory of an ever-expanding spiral.